# Unable to install locust on windows

Tags: python-3.7, gevent, locust

Hi i am trying to install locust on windows with python version 3.7.3, using pip install locustio but getting below error.

ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: I have not installed .whl file, so i think thats why i am getting above error, but I don't know which .whl file i should download that will support to python 3.7.3 version

Comment: Have you tried the solutions suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962678/installing-chatterbot-but-getting-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-spacy-which

Comment: thanks but it has been resolved now

Answer (score 0):

I was getting above error because Visual Studio was not installed in my machine. When I did I was able to install locust, and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Had faced a similiar issue on MacOS.
The MacOS Catalina update upgraded my system python was 3.8. (Gevent works with <3.7)
Installing a lower version with pyenv fixed it.